# Xcode generate NSManagedObject Subclass issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

After I set up Core Data Stack, I generated the NSManagedObject Subclass automatically.

However, I received the error in xcode 8, which is very annoying. [image]

[image]

Comment: Check if you have same file twice?

Comment: You mean header files or something else?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try and clean your build as well

Comment: I have tried it and I cant find any duplicate files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I also ran in this issue. You have to disable automatical code generation if you want to create the NSManagedObjects by yourself. So there are different ways. First way is go to your model and changed the Toolversion to xCode 7.3.
In every entity you can set the Codegen to Manual/None like in the Screenshot. 
Clean your project, and try again!
I hope this was helpful. 
[image]

Comment: I disable the Codegen to Manual/None as you did, and i generated the core data NSManagedObject by selecting entity -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass, after it, it is still same error.

Comment: The complier error is because the classes are there twice.... Pleas delete the generated classes and try again.

Comment: Ok, it works now. And one more question, if I delete the generated classes, in other View Controller, if I need to save the location data, do I have to import the location header file ？

Comment: If you want to access the location class you have to import the "Location+CoreDataClass.h" file... I'm also struggeling around with this new shit sometimes. I don't know what apple wants to effect with the new way... I don't use the autogenerated shit...